# Formulating a PostGIS query as data-source for a virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, virtual-layer

While this seems to be an obvious application of virtual layers, I could not find a full description anywhere how to achieve it:

- I want to create a virtual layer that contains the results of a    PostGIS query (e.g. the content of a table in a remote database).
- This virtual layer should be permanent in my QGIS project.
- It should always reflect the latest content in the PostGIS database - so I do not want to e.g. create a virtual layer from a local project layer that was filled with a query but does not update.

Is this actually possible? I tried to create a virtual layer both by Layer/Add and Layer/Create (the difference between the two is, by the way, not really explained). If, in the "create" dialog, I click "import", I see my project layers. Choosing one fills the "local name", "source" and "provider" columns. A "test" (see example below) fails with `Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(Table_A-B_C-D_E): near "-": syntax error`. Should this work, and is the error related to characters in the table name?

Example (strings replaced):

```
dbname='mydb_dev' host=db.my-domain.net port=5432 authcfg=abcd123 key='id' type=Point checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="table_name"."layer_with-special_characters" (geom)
```

Comment: Yes this should work. But actually you dont need a virtual layer for that - you can just add a PostGIS query as layer. Seems like you just have a syntax error in your query, can you add the query as formatted text to your question?

Comment: Hyphens are not SQL-standard identifier characters. Best practice is to just use alphanumeric and underscore in identifiers, but PostgreSQL will let you use quotes for non-conformant names.

Comment: @MrXsquared: Does this mean I could just add layers (e.g. by dragging the same table in the data-sources tab into the project several times) and that these are kept synchronised with the DB? I added an example query (with anonymized strings).

Comment: @Vince: Thank you for clarifying this. To my understanding, the strings should be sufficiently quoted, but I may still do a test with a table not containing any non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Have you tried [PostgreSQL execute and load SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#qgispostgisexecuteandloadsql) instead of a Virtual Layer?

Comment: @larsg yes, tables and queries from postgis keep synchronised. They will always show the latest data. -- I meant to show the query, not the connection parameters.